# Running Docker in Ubuntu Bionic Container

Tags: docker

I am installing Docker CE on the latest Ubuntu Docker image and getting the following error. I followed installation instructions carefully; maybe installing Docker on a Docker container is not the way to go about this? I'm working with Jenkins Pipelines and have Jenkins installed on the Ubuntu container; the next piece is to get Docker running.

```
time="2018-10-26T13:25:09.920187300Z" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
time="2018-10-26T13:25:09.920228600Z" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock 0  <nil>}]" module=grpc
time="2018-10-26T13:25:09.920250500Z" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
time="2018-10-26T13:25:09.920286200Z" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420047e60, CONNECTING" module=grpc
time="2018-10-26T13:25:09.920480100Z" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420047e60, READY" module=grpc
time="2018-10-26T13:25:09.920501400Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
time="2018-10-26T13:25:09.920666400Z" level=warning msg="Running modprobe bridge br_netfilter failed with message: , error: exec: \"modprobe\": executable file not found in $PATH"
time="2018-10-26T13:25:09.920704800Z" level=warning msg="Running modprobe nf_nat failed with message: ``, error: exec: \"modprobe\": executable file not found in $PATH"
time="2018-10-26T13:25:09.920733300Z" level=warning msg="Running modprobe xt_conntrack failed with message: ``, error: exec: \"modprobe\": executable file not found in $PATH"
Error starting daemon: Error initializing network controller: error obtaining controller instance: failed to create NAT chain DOCKER: iptables failed: iptables -t nat -N DOCKER: iptables v1.6.1: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Permission denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
 (exit status 3)
```

Comment: Let's say you can't install Docker inside a Docker image; it's almost certainly not the right solution, it's complicated on its own, Docker discourages it, and it leads to confusion about which Docker you're actually talking to.  What's your higher-level goal?  Usual answers are "use the host's Docker" or "use a VM".

Answer (score 0):

A typical Docker container is run with a restricted set of permissions.  Even if you are `root` in the container, you cannot modify the network configuration, nor can you mount filesystems.  So the error you are seeing...

> Error starting daemon: Error initializing network controller: error obtaining controller instance: failed to create NAT chain DOCKER: iptables failed: iptables -t nat -N DOCKER: iptables v1.6.1: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Permission denied (you must be root)

...is happening because of that restriction.  You can create an
unrestricted container by creating with your container with:

```
docker run --privileged ...
```

You *may* be able to use something slightly more granular and grant
the `NET_ADMIN` capability, as in:

```
docker run --cap-add NET_ADMIN ...
```

This will work as long as the only "special" privilege required by the container is network configuration.

Comment: Re: @user3423536's comment, see "[Using Docker-in-Docker for your CI or testing environment? Think twice.](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/)"